# AngularJS ui-router redirect after log in

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, rootscope

I have a project using AngularJS with ui-router. Everything working fine beside the redirect from login screen to preview state on the first load.

Default state is home - http://test/#/

For example, if user is not logged in - http://test/#/test/1000/details goes to login page (which it is supposed to do)

Then after user login, the system goes to default state "home - http://test/#/" but I want to go to http://test/#/requests/1000/details

How do I save the "http://test/#/requests/1000/details or stateName" to redirect after login?

I try using `$stateChangeSuccess` to save a log of states in the `$rootscope` but the first one (http://test/#/requests/1000/details) never gets saved.

Any ideas how to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just another answer to look at
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886677/3659003

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a 'previous' property to $state in your main-app's run method.

This is how I solved the problem:

```
// add ui-router variables to $rootScope. Comes handy in many cases, for example setting page title
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', addUIRouterVars]);

function addUIRouterVars($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    // add previous state property
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        $state.previous = fromState;
    });
}
```

Comment: I added this but it is saving {url="^", abstract=true, name="", views=null, transition=null}, it is not saving the right data, it should be {url="http://test/#/request/1000/details, etc...}, Correct?

Comment: It works for me.

It can look like this for example:

Object {url: "/posts", templateUrl: "../AngularApp/post/posts.html", data: Object, resolve: Object, controller: "postsCtrl as vm"…}

Your values are the defaults values I think, which will be there if there is no previous state yet (ie. you started your app with that state).

Comment: If you want to read more about this, try this thread:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/92

Comment: Hi Joe, after closer look... there was code that redirect to the homepage after login every time. This works now. Thanks.